# Excel make a list with a specific conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work in a hospital, have a list of patients, with name, date of admission, date of dismiss, and diagnosis. I need a list with all data when date of dismiss is blank, if contain something must skip data. I try several formulas but can't find the one that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't Need formulas for this, Just use Data Filter:

1. Select the "Date of Dismiss" column, go to **Data > Filter** or Click **(Ctrl+Shift+L)** on your Keyboard

[image]

2. Click on the small drop-down filter arrow on top of your column, now uncheck Select All and check **(blanks)**

[image]

3. Excel will filter the data showing only the rows with blank "Date of dismiss"

[image]

4. You can now edit you data or copy it or whatever you want to do, and once you're done just click on the drop-down arrow and click "Clear Filters"

Comment: LOL. "[DOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOA)" also means "Dead on Arrival" ;)